# How to manage Maven dependencies on multiple platforms?

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Maven and I am trying to figure out whether and I can accomplish the following.

My Java project should be available both on a Linux and a Mac machine. I have a number of dependencies which I can find on the maven repository. However, I have a dependency (a jar file) which must be local on both machines.

How can I set up my POM file, and project structure to achieve this?

**Update**:
Part of this information seems to be provided here in this other question: [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project).
What I still don't understand is whether having the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Name_Your_JAR.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

implies that on both machines I need to manually copy the jar file.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple platforms? Do you have platform dependent code? And what do you means by `which must be local on both machines.`?

Comment: I vote to close this as a duplicate. But I must say that the only answer I endorse myself is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762617/424903

Comment: I don't understand why there should be a local jar. Why can't you load it from a repository or at least a local repository?

Comment: @khmarbaise Let me try: I have the same source code. It needs to be developed both on a Mac and a Linux machine, with git coordinating the efforts. Most dependencies are on maven repository. There is however a jar file which must be used. I suppose this should be on both machines, and I am trying to setup my maven project in the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the local repo solution. [The system scope is more or less deprecated](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#system-dependencies).

Beside, the local repo solution will be standard and won't enforce the user to have some path/variable: it will only have to register the local repositories in its maven settings.

This will left out the question of how to share the repository:

- Using a shared folder or archive: you can use the [assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) plugin to generate an archive will all dependencies and following the repository tree.
- You can use the [install](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin) plugin as shown in other answer to install to a local repository, which you can share using git (not the "best" usage of git).
- You can use a repository manager such as Sonatype Nexus and the [deploy](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin) plugin to deploy it (the goals and settings are almost the same as the one found in install plugin).

It really depends on the purpose and scope of your team.